# When I have 2 OSGi bundles which use the same jar, do they need this jar in each bundle or one out is sufficient?

Tags: java, osgi, bundle

For example, a bundle 'A' and a bundle 'B' are using log4j. Can we have only one log4j ? or is it necessary to have log4j inside each bundle?

Answer (score 5):

Bundle 'B' can use the log4j in bundle 'A' if bundle 'A' is exporting log4j packages and bundle 'B' imports them.

It is actually a better idea to instead use the [log4j bundle](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar) (log4j 1.2.16 is an OSGi compliant release) and then have 'A' and 'B' import it. You can inspect the log4j.jar I linked and see that it has OSGi manifest entries.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what others have said. Not only is it possible to only have one copy of the log4j jar, it's highly desirable. Avoiding this kind of duplication of jars is one of the main use cases of OSGi. Instead of defensively packaging libraries inside bundles to ensure they're on the classpath, each bundle can explicitly declare a dependency on the library packages - log4j in this case. This avoids bloat and also makes it much easier to update the shared library if required.

Answer (score 0):

If you share a bundle it will only have one global state (static fields etc).

Usually you can re-use log4j, but if you want a package to be in DEBUG level for one application and INFO in another, you need to maintain two bundles.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of OSGi is to be able to share ...

That said, sharing creates coupling and in general you want to only couple to public API. Bad bundles are bundles that seem to transitively drag in an endless number of dependencies. The whole idea of OSGi services is to minimize the big ball of mud that people create when they couple too much to other bundles.